# 2 WordPress site, Sub directory site giving 404

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Here is a situation

I have `example.org` and `example.org/dev` with following code, I have made subdirectory '`dev`' as subdomain i.e `dev.example.org`. Both sites are WordPress site.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.org$
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ http://dev.example.org/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Now problem is 
`example.org` works OK, but I can not access any page of `dev.example.org` I get a `404` at every page.

Further more, wp-admin is redirecting to HTTPS/SSL although I have set it to be false `(define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', false );)`

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. It might help you.

```
`# 301 redirect for main pages
RedirectMatch 301 ^/Your_dir/$ http://Your_domain.main_domain.com/`
```